# Working with a subtheme

Tags: theming

I am customizing my sub-theme and looking to see where to place styling rules. My web inspector is not showing me the specific files where the base theme rules are, it just show that all the rules are in foundation_subtheme.css.  I don't believe that I have any aggregation turned on, what do I need to do to see the specific files that the styling rules are inside of?

For example, how do I fine this rule?

```
.top-bar input, .top-bar select, .top-bar .button, .top-bar #contact-btn, .top-bar .button-ghost, .top-bar button {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    height: 1.75rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.53125rem;
}
```

Even when I add a rule to _header.scss the web inspector doesn't show me that its there it only shows the main css file.

Comment: Rules? CSS? I feel confused. Do the rules mean the content of css files?

Comment: Yes - like .top-bar input, .top-bar select, .top-bar .button, .top-bar #contact-btn, .top-bar .button-ghost, .top-bar button {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    height: 1.75rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.53125rem;
}

Comment: I never see people describing it as 'rules', I ask this because I want to sync our understandings :)

Comment: And which base theme you are using? You can check which CSS files has been loaded on **Network** tabs in the Chrome developer tools. In Firefox, the tab is **Net**.

Comment: I am using zurb foundation theme.

Comment: I overlooked your question. You are asking about sass file....

Answer (score 0):

scss isn't parsed by the browser- it needs to be compiled to css... ,Assuming you have already installed ruby and sass, open a terminal window and navigate to your theme's root directory. Then `sass --update` to compile the styles once or `sass --watch` to continue compiling as you work.

Comment: Yes - I am doing that.  But shouldn't I still be able to see which sass file its compiling from?

Comment: In `config.rb` you'll find the sass parameters- change the output style to 'expanded'